# Allowing an anonymous person to post a value

Tags: django, session

An anonymous user (no login) gets directed to a landing page where there is a button and text field to post information.

I want the act posting of data to be tied to the person landing on the page. ie knowing the target url of the post shouldn't allow you to post stuff, it should be tied to a very short duration session.

I am using Django.

What is the simplest or built in method to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Sessions

You can store this information in the anonymous user's session if you have a session store configured.  To start the session:

```
request.session["allow_post_until"] = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(...)
```

And to check it:

```
if not (request.session["allow_post_until"] and request.session["allow_post_until"] < datetime.datetime.now()):
    raise PermissionDenied
```

### Signed Cookies

If you are using django 1.4 and don't want to configure a session store you can use signed cookies for this.  When you want to enable a session for the user, set a cookie with an appropriate max_age.  When a user posts, check for the signed cookie and check its validity.  To set:

```
response.set_signed_cookie("mysession", "sessiondata", max_age=<session period in seconds>)
```

To check:

```
request.get_signed_cookie("mysession", max_age=<session period in seconds>)
```

Comment: Note that with any of these methods, another user could post to the form by copying the cookies of the valid user (session hijacking).